# replace a string pattern in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I know there are many questions regarding regex and my question would be answered somewhere. but I can't find the correct answer.

I just wanted to remove a simple string pattern. If there is any numeric values or numeric values with symbols after the word "AA" and before "," I wanted to remove those. For example,

```
tmp1= "B1, AA1~11, B22"
tmp2 = "AA2, 13, C1"
tmp3 = "1, 2, 3, AA-3"
```

my desired output is

```
tmp1= "B1, B22"
tmp2 = "13, C1"
tmp3 = "1, 2"
```

This is what I tried

```
str_replace_all(tmp1,"(AA)(\\d+)((?=,)",replacement= "")
```

Comment: The `tmp2` example there is no symbol in `AA2`
The `tmp3` example `AA-3`, after it doesn't have any `,`

Comment: Why is the output of tmp3, removing the 3,

Comment: @Shinh, updated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your examples are super confusing, but something like this should work:

```
tmp1= "B1, AA1~11, B22"
tmp2 = "AA2, 13, C1"
tmp3 = "1, 2, 3, AA-3"

f = function(x){
    gsub('AA[^A-Za-z ]*?', '', x, perl=T)
}

> f(tmp1)
[1] "B1,  B22"
> f(tmp2)
[1] " 13, C1"
> f(tmp3)
[1] "1, 2, 3, AA-3"
```

If you want to remove the trailing space in tmp2 and the trailing AA-3 in tmp3, then maybe:

```
f = function(x){
    gsub('AA[^A-Za-z ]*[,$]* ?', '', x)
}

> f(tmp1)
[1] "B1, B22"
> f(tmp2)
[1] "13, C1"
> f(tmp3)
[1] "1, 2, 3, "
```

But in order to get better feedback, you should really invest more time into making better examples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that any sequence of non-space characters containing AA is to be eliminated, split up the fields using `scan`, remove those with `AA` using `grep` and then put it back together using `toString`.

```
stripAA <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 1) return(sapply(x, stripAA, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
  x2 <- scan(text = x, what = "", quiet = TRUE, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
  x3 <- grep("AA", x2, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
  toString(x3)
}

stripAA(tmp1)
## [1] "B1, B22"
stripAA(tmp2)
## [1] "13, C1"
stripAA(tmp3)
## [1] "1, 2, 3"

stripAA(c(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3))   # all at once
## [1] "B1, B22" "13, C1"  "1, 2, 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why 3 is removed from the output in `tmp3` but here is an attempt with `sub` and `trimws`.

```
trimws(sub('AA.*?(,|$)', '', c(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3)), whitespace = '[,|\\s]')
#[1] "B1,  B22" "13, C1"   "1, 2, 3"
```

Using `sub` we remove characters that start with `'AA'` until a comma or end of the string. Remove the leftover commas and whitespace using `trimws`.